# python tar extra pax header folders

Tags: python, filesystems, tar, opensuse, suse

It seems like a reported bug in some versions but does anybody seen this issue and provide a workaround or any solution?

in python code when i execute subprocess(["tar","czf","pack.tar.gz","pack"])

generated archive file contains magical **PaxHeaders.15790** in all directories :D

I am using tar = 1.28 and python = 2.7.8

Edit: this is not related to python, also same folder has same problem with regular shell commands. tar xvzf and tar cvzf....

I found this but didn't help :https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/5783

Also i am using opensuse

Comment: Are yo able to try with the option --format=gnu as shown in the issue report?

Comment: I tried it, it didn't help. I gave up because it only happens with 1.28